# Typescript: A spread argument must either have a tuple - with Object.values

Tags: typescript

When trying to use `Object.values` I'm getting this error:

```
const a ={
  b: this.formLayout,
  c: 4,
  d: 3,
}
this.formPayload.layout = formPayloadAction(...(Object.values(a)) as const);
//
    A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter
```

However when just using an array instead:

```
this.formPayload.layout = formPayloadAction(...([this.formLayout, 30,3] as const));
```

How is it possible that `Object.values`which just creates an array from the values of an object, doesn't work here while an array does?

The signature of formPayloadAction is:

```
formPayloadAction: (
  ...params: updateNumberOfSelectedColumnsArgs
) => Array<Array<FieldId>>,

type updateNumberOfSelectedColumnsArgs = [
  formLayout: Array<Array<FieldId>>,
  row: number,
  selectedNumberOfColumns: number,
];
```

Comment: What is the signature of `formPayloadAction`?

Comment: Your second example is not an array. Your second example is a readonly tuple that TypeScript can infer because its length is *static* (3).

Comment: Also, `Object.values` isn't safe. The order of the values it returns may be the order they are defined, but what if you're using it on some object from a third-party source?

Comment: Yes but isn't using 'as const' makes it static? VLAZ I updated my question thank you

Comment: @caTS so what should you do in this case to ensure it's safe? Thanks

Comment: Don't use Object.values?

Comment: But I'm receiving the arguments as an object on which I'd like to check a few things on its properties and then call that function. Isn't calling it with Object.values my only option?

Comment: "*isn't using 'as const' makes it static*" no, it tells the compiler to treat it as unchanging. But it's already coming from a non-const source, thus it cannot be relied on.

Comment: "*Isn't calling it with Object.values my only option?*" no: `fn(a.b, a.c, a.d)` is quite a correct way to do this. Or just accept an object, so you don't have to rely on the position of the arguments.